# Showing 4 points are concyclic

Tags: geometry

I have the following statement that I have to prove. It is supposed to be a geometric proof. I have somewhat started the proof but I am stumped. Here is the statement.

> Given any triangle, let A, B, C be the midpoints of the three sides of a triangle and let D be the base of one of the altitudes. Show that these 4 points are concyclic.

So far this is what I have...

Connect the points A, B and C to form a triangle. We know that any triangle has a circumscribed circle and so the points A, B and C all lie on the circumference of this circle. Now we want to show that D also lies on this circle. If X, Y, Z is our initial triangle, we note that AC // XZ, BC //XY and AB // YZ.

I do not know how to continue after this. Please help me!

Comment: For specificity, suppose $A$ and $D$ lie on the same side of the triangle. Show that $\triangle BAC \cong \triangle CDB$. Then, since $\angle BAC \cong \angle CDB$, the inscribed angle theorem implies that the four points are concyclic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$AHC$ is a right triangle and the median relative to hypotenuse is half the hypotenuse

$AH=\frac12 FD\to AH=AD$

$ADCB$ is a parallelogram so AD=BC$

therefore $AH=BC$

Furthermore $AB\parallel DE$ and this proves that $ABCH$ is an isosceles trapezoid which is always possible to inscribe in a circle.

Hope this helps

*EDIT*

The median $AH$ is half $DF$ because you can build a rectangle as I did in the second picture,  diagonals are equal and bisect each other.
$$...$$

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

They are all on Euler or nine point circle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_circle

You can do it like this. Say $C,D$ are on $XY$, then $BD =XZ/2 = AC$ and $DC||AB$ so $ABCD$ is isosceles trapezoid and thus it is cyclic.

Comment: Yes, I know that but how would I prove that these four points are on the same circle. I am pretty sure it is wrong for me to solely state that these points are all on the nine point circle.